# if-conditions in Twig

Tags: php, templates, symfony, twig

I am using Twig to conditionally display a piece of HTML (or trying to, anyway).

What is wrong with this? Everything works okay until I put in the if-endif pair.

```
{% set numberOfPartners = partners|length %}
(% if numberOfPartners > 1 || partners[0].special != 1 %}
<div id="headline">
{% trans %}   
  Lorem ipsum dolor
  {{ numberOfPartners }}
  <br />
{% endtrans %} 
</div>
{% endif %}
```

The error I get is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'Unknown tag name "endif" in ...

Comment: I can't find tag `trans` here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html

It works without the IF around it...

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually looked at the code or tested it, but is it because you've got `(%` instead of `{%` on line 2?

Comment: Believe it or not, I have been staring at my code for about half an hour and did not see that. You saved me. I am going to delete this stupid question ;) Maybe it's time I turn my machine of for the day.

Comment: Ha, we've all spent hours on that accidentally-capitalized letter or missing semicolon!

And I wouldn't delete it... That error message isn't very helpful (should probably say something like "unmatched 'endif' tag"), so someone searching for "Unknown tag name 'endif'" might find their answer here too.